# Create PDF forms with ghostcript usable with evince

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation, ghostscript, postscript

I am trying to create a simple PDF form with ghostscript. I get functional forms in acrobat reader, however, I cannot fill the forms with my usual PDF viewer evince. Now I have PDF forms I can fill with evince, e.g. [this one](http://foersom.com/org/HowTo/data/OoPdfFormExample.pdf), so it should be possible.

Here is a minimal example of what I try to do:
I create a postscript file with the following contents:

```
%!PS
/Courier    
12 selectfont   
15 500 moveto
(text input:) show 
/pdfmark where {pop} {userdict /pdfmark /cleartomark load put} ifelse
[/Rect[100 495 200 510] /T (input) /FT /Tx/F 4 /Subtype /Widget /ANN pdfmark
showpage
```

I convert it to pdf using:

```
gs -q -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -o out.pdf in.ps
```

The resulting PDF works fine in acrobat reader but in evince I do not get any text input field.

Does anyone know of a way to create a simple form PDF using ghostcript that works with evince?